# Explain why two students will have shaken the same number of hands.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, pigeonhole-principle

Question: Twenty-five students attend a class reunion and shake hands with each other. If no student shakes hands with the same person twice, explain why two students will have shaken the same number of hands.

So far, the furthest I've gotten is finding the number of possible handshake combinations which would be (25 x 24)/2 = 300 (using n(n-1)/2). This question seems to be a pigeonhole principle question. I am new to this topic however, so my understanding is elementary and insufficient to answer this.

Comment: If each person shakes hands with at least one other person, then for any given person X, the number of people that this person has shaken hands with is some element in $\{1,2,\cdots,24\}$.  This is because no person shakes hands with someone else twice.

Comment: Re previous comment, it is actually unnecessary to presume that each person has shaken hands with one other person.  The attempt at counter example would have that each element in $\{0,1,\cdots,24\}$ represents the number of people that some person has shaken hands with.  This is impossible, because if somebody shook hands with all $24$ other people, then nobody could have shaken hands with $0$ people.

Comment: Re first comment : minor typo : intended " ...then for any given person X, the number of hands that this person has shaken is some element in ...".

Comment: can't all 25 people shake all other 24 hands?

Comment: @ness Your example would imply that there are at least $2$ people (in fact all $25$ people) that have shaken hands with the same number of people (i.e. with $24$ people).  Given that $x_i$ represents the number of hands that person $i$ shook hands with, the challenge is to prove that it is impossible for $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{25}\}$ to comprise $25$ distinct numbers.